# Having trouble scaling height of ImageView so that position does not change

Tags: javascript, java, arduino

I am trying to display an image that shows how much liquid is left in a container. So I have an image of "liquid", which is just an orange square,  and I am programmatically changing the Height of this image here:

```
int newHeight = 802*finalPercent;
chem.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
```

And it is scaling properly, but when the image scales, it does so toward the center of the ImageView boundary.

This liquid image is supposed to be inside a static container image, so how can I make it scale but keep the image bottom at the bottom of the container?
Images:

https://ibb.co/Cn5t40m

https://ibb.co/z5YznFq

I've tried changing constraints to the outline, to the edge, to just about everything.

I've tried adjustViewBounds, to no effect.

I've tried every scaleType, to little or no effect.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/chem"
android:layout_width="229dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:minWidth="572dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:scaleY="1"
android:visibility="visible"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/zero"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.193"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/zero"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/full" />
```

I want to scale the image and keep it at the bottom of the black outline "container" in the image, but it is scaling to center.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Figured it out.

Set my outside image (bounding box image) to FitEnd, and the inner image to scale to Center. Brought both images back to image editor and cut off all vertical extra transparent area. Set bottom constraint of inside image to bottom of bounding box image. Can now scale vertical and image bottom stays where it needs to be.